# How do I edit the CSS of the Html.DisplayFor method in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, .net, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following code to display text from my view model in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
```

When I look at the HTML details in IE9 (which I have to use at work) there is no class associated with the name, it just uses the Body CSS styling instead of the display-field class styling. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or how I might edit the CSS for the text created?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DisplayFor is used for templating reasons.  If you aren't using a template, then you should just use the item like so: `@Model.Name`  If you want to give it a class or id, then you need to wrap it in a span or div.

Your problem is that you're using the wrong method to output data, and expecting it to do something else.  There is no built-in way to output raw data with class names.

So your choices are, wrap the raw item in a container that you can apply the css to, or create a template to use for these, then specify the template name in the DisplayFor like so:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name, "NameTemplate")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to MVC 3 / web development and am not aware of what templating means exactly.

Comment: @barnone - you'll want to read this http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html/

Comment: So this rules out using LabelFor unless it's an editor, because LabelFor will generate a 'for=' attribute pointing to an ID that doesn't exist, since DisplayFor doesn't generate an ID for the model property it's displaying.  Great.  Awesome, intuitive design :/

Comment: @Triynko - You seem to have gone off into left field based on a bizarre assumption which isn't true.

Answer (score 17):

if it is a label, use proper helper for it as Nataka526 suggests

otherwise put it in a span with a class and update css for that class:

**your html:**

```
<span class="name">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
</span>
```

**your css:**

```
.name {
    //custom css
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another option:
Update your Display Templates to handle a specific ViewData key:

in Views > Shared > DisplayTemplate (create this folder if you don't have it already):

add file String.cshtml:

```cs
@model string

@{
    string myClass = ViewData["class"]
}

@if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myClass))
{
    @:@Model
}
else
{
    <span class="@myClass">@Model</span>
}
```

you may need to add DisplayTemplates for other tipes as well besides string.

In the view you will write something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name, new { @class= "name" })
```

This will add spans around it automatically.

**UPDATE**

Explanation:

There is an overload on `Html.DisplayFor` which accepts two parameters: expression and `object additionalViewData`. So the second parameter that I pass is that anonymous object additionalViewData. I create this object with property called `class`

Inside of the html helper I then check if there is a ViewData with a key `class` and if there is, I put output inside a span with that class value.

**
updated variable name from `class` to `myClass` since "class" is not appropriate variable name.

Comment: I have a lot of DisplayFors I would need to encapsulate with spans, but I will try this method if no one else suggests another method.

Comment: what is the reason you are using DisplayFor? Please confirm it is not a label for an input. If it is, it would be a simple fix.

Comment: Sorry guys my answer was wrong... So i voted to delete it as it will mislead someone..

Comment: DisplayFor because I just want to display the value in the model.name property as text. This is for a confirmation screen to display changes made.

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I don't quite understand your use of the class keyword in the example, but this looks interesting.

Comment: Updated answer with explanation. Let me know if there is something else I can help you with.

Comment: also fixed some minor bugs and typos

Comment: sorry, I should have provided a link to some basic info about templates in mvc. Basically in my solution I am customizing one of these templates.