# How to pass the div value not part of model to backend controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Question:** I want to have **one div in UI** and I want to render some value into it via **JQuery** and when I submit the form I should be able to access it in the **backend**.

**View:**

```
 @model ScheduleAptMV
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
           ////// I want a div here /////
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            <input type="submit" value="Make Appointment"/>
        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class ScheduleAptMV
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDelayedPayment(ScheduleAptMV data)
    {
         // I want to be able to access the Div text too
    }
```

**Partial Solution 1:**

I added a div

```
  <div id="totalAmount"></div>
```

And with Jquery I added something like

```
$("#totalAmount").text("HelloFoo");
```

But my problem is it is not tied to the model, so **how to send** it to the backend.

**Partial Solution 2:**

I can create a *property* in my model which will *represent that div content* so that it gets Strongly Bound. This value is *just for display* user *should
not* be allowed to edit it, only it should by rendered by Jquery code. I can use

```
 @Html.DisplayFor()
```

Something like below:

New Model:

```
public class ScheduleAptMV
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public decimal totalAmount{get; set;}
}
```

New View:

```
<span class="myClass">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.totalAmount)
</span>
```

Question: But now *how to render* this property using *Jquery*. Do I need to use something else apart from `DisplayFor`.

Edit: This is how the `DisplayFor` renders currently.

```
  <span class="myClass">
    0.00
        </span>
```

**Question:** If I follow soution 2 then how to attach a class to `DisplayFor` Element.

Comment: what does `<span class="myClass">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.totalAmount)</span>` render into, right now?

Comment: @Scaramouche: Added the edit

Comment: In Partial Solution 1, you can use hidden element, why not use it?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr: can you kindly guide me on how to send it to the backend then. Thanks

Comment: I think it was already part of an answer below by freedomn-m

Comment: @WillyDavidJr: I want to follow second solution, but I am not sure how to render its value using Jquery becase we cannot add a class to `DisplayFor` Element. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Change your action signature to

```
public ActionResult SaveDelayedPayment(ScheduleAptMV data, int totalAmount)
```

however it must be a POSTable entity, eg a textbox, *not* a div.  So add a hidden input:

```
<input type='hidden' name='totalAmount' id='totalAmount'/>
<div id='totalAmountDisplay'></div>
```

and set accordingly:

```
 $("#totalAmountDisplay").text("1024");
 $("#totalAmount").val(1024);
```

---

**Solution 2**

Similar to solution 1, you just need a hidden input so that it can be POSTed:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.totalAmount)
```

ensure that's within the `<form>` and it will be bound automatically.  Add the display using `.DisplayFor` or however else you like and jquery to update (if required) similar to above.

Comment: Suppose I want to follow solution 2nd, then my doubt is, how to change its value in frontend using Jquery. I don't think I can add a class to `DisplayFor` helper.

Comment: I understood the hiddenFor part. Now I want to understand how to adjust the value using Jquery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546963/applying-css-class-using-html-displayfor-inside-razor-view Kindly see this example. It just renders a text and class does not get attached to it.

Comment: If you look at the rendered html, `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.totalAmount)` will be rendered as `<input name='totalAmount' id='totalAmount'/>` so you just use `$("#totalAmount").val(123);`

Comment: As it's hidden, if you want to see it, you also need to change the display version, as per the solution 1 solution.

Comment: Perfect then I think I will not use DisplayFor then. I wil simply use a bare div element and display the value using jquery as mentioned in solution 1 and as far as sending strongly typed value is concerned I will use the `HiddenFor`. I hope I am making sense. (So, no need to use DisplayFor).