# Dynamic changing of view

Tags: .net, razor

Please explain how can I change the color of the text in the row(i think it should be class for ) depending on the value of the element **item.Status**.

```
<tbody>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @{ if (item.Status != 0) {
      <del> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</del> } else { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) } }
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What `string` are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying css class using Html.DisplayFor inside razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546963/applying-css-class-using-html-displayfor-inside-razor-view)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use auxiliary variable for this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  bool itemStatusOk = item != 0;
  <tr class="@(itemStatusOk ? "X" : "Y")">
    <td>
      @if (itemStatusOk)
        { <del> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</del> }
        else
        { @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) }
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
    </td>
  </tr>
 }
```

Comment: I mean that i need to change color for whole row in a table

Comment: Aha, ok. Answer changed.