# MVC3 passing incorrectly formatted datetime to Controller but correcting it in the Controller action gives ModelState error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, controller, modelstate

Am I the only one having this problem or I am doing it in totally wrong direction.

I have a View passing DateTime value:

```
<div class="control-group">
@Html.Label("Appointment date", null, new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input-append">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Appointment.Client_PreferredDate, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
        <span class="add-on margin-fix"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>
    <p class="help-block">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Appointment.Client_PreferredDate)
    </p>
</div>
```

The values are passed into the Controller action ( I can see the value, and I know it is giving the format that is not DateTime, i.e. it is going to be in dd-MM-yyyy). Then in the Controller I will reformat it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestAppointment(General_Enquiry model, FormCollection fc)

{       
    model.Appointment.Client_PreferredDate = Utilities.formatDate(fc["Appointment.Client_PreferredDate"]);
    ModelState.Remove("Appointment.Client_PreferredDate");

try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.Branch_Id = Convert.ToInt32(fc["selectedBranch"]);
        model.Appointment.Branch_Id = Convert.ToInt32(fc["selectedBranch"]);
        db.General_Enquiry.AddObject(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AppointmentSuccess", "Client");
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", e);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
    ModelState.AddModelError("", e);
}

return View(model);
```

}

The best I can do is to use ModelState.Remove(), which I feel really uncomfortable with. I suspect that when my Model is passed from the View to Controller, the ModelState is already set to Invalid before I can do anything in the Controller. Any ideas?

If I call the ModelState.Remove() everything went smoothly, the DateTime is accepted by SQL server database.

If at least I can update or 'refresh' ModelState at any point it'll fix my problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you using a view model and a custom model binder for the DateTime formats.

We start by defining this view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime PreferredDate { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            PreferredDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // model.PreferredDate will be correctly bound here so
        // that you don't need to twiddle with any FormCollection and 
        // removing stuff from ModelState, etc...
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

a View:

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PreferredDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PreferredDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PreferredDate)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally a custom model binder to use the specified format:

```
public class MyDateTimeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var displayFormat = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayFormatString;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayFormat) && value != null)
        {
            DateTime date;
            displayFormat = displayFormat.Replace("{0:", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty);
            // use the format specified in the DisplayFormat attribute to parse the date
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, displayFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName,
                    string.Format("{0} is an invalid date format", value.AttemptedValue)
                );
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

that will be registered in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new MyDateTimeModelBinder());
```

Comment: What is the purpose of model binder? wouldnt the attribute sufficient enough for Datetime format?

Comment: @DarthVader, the DisplayFormat is used to specify the format that you want to use when outputting the value in the view. It has nothing to do with model binding back this value back to the model. The default model binder uses the current culture date format when binding back. But since the OP wants to specify a custom date format you need a custom model binder. In my example the model binder simply reads the same format used for displaying the date on the view from the DisplayFormat attribute.

Comment: So I will have to define ViewModel for each Model that has DateTime type in it? Or at least use the `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`? I am asking because I am using generated Models from Database with EntityFramework. :/

Comment: Yes, you have to use view models and not only for that. It's just the correct way to do ASP.NET MVC. Never pass your autogenerated entities to the views. Always use view models. But if you want to violate those recommendations you could adapt the code in the model binder and hardcode the date format you want to be used instead of retrieving it from the `DisplayFormat` attribute.