# ASP.NET MVC and Jquery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to use jQuery UI date picker with the following date field

```
 <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalibrationDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CalibrationDate)
  </div>
```

I have already include required script and the following function in my view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }
    });
```

It seems that I need to assign date class to my

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalibrationDate)
```

Can you please suggest me how to do that? or any other approach to get this functionality?

---

Based on comments, here is the final working code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".date").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

and in the body

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CalibrationDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CalibrationDate,  new{ Class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CalibrationDate)
        </div>
```

Comment: this might answer you question.

[StackOver Question 4576209][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor

Comment: alternative way (editor template) : http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `EditorFor` an anonymous object with a class member as its `additionalViewData` parameter.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CalibrationDate, new { @class = "date" })
```

Note: Using an `@` symbol in front of a keyword allows us to use it as an identifier.