# Format DateTime in MVC4 via Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties

I have created a class that maps to my database model. One of the properties is StartDate

`public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }`

I can easily grab this while building my model and place it in my view.

What I would like to do is have the view show a more friendly date MM/dd/yyyy.  I'm aware of the `.ToString(MM/dd/yyyy)` and have attempted to use properties to set it.  I'm having troubles because the database is set as a nullable DateTime and I'd like to return a string.  Maybe I'm not using the correct approach

Code to retrieve from db

```
var newsItem = (from n in context.News
                    where n.NewsID == id
                    select new Models.Components.NewsModel
                    {
                        NewsId = n.NewsID,
                        Header = n.Header,
                        MainPhoto = n.MainImage,
                        Text = n.Text,
                        Date = n.CreatedDate,
                        Active = n.Active,
                        StartDate = n.StartDate,                                                                
                        EndDate = n.EndDate
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Trying to set the value

```
private DateTime? _StartDate { get; set; }
public string StartDate
{
    get
    {
        DateTime tmp;
        DateTime.TryParse(_StartDate.ToString(), out tmp);
        return tmp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    set { _StartDate = value; }
}
```

This complains because _StartDate is a DateTime? value

What is the most efficient way to display the date in the format I specified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume `NewsModel` is some kind of view model.  In which case you can just decorate your property with some data annotations:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

In order for this to work, you need to make use of the HTML helpers:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StartDate)
```

If you want to do this format to also be applied when you use any HTML editor helper (e.g. `Html.EditorFor`, `Html.TextBoxFor`, ...), you also need to specify `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` for the `DisplayFormat` attribute.  So the property would end up being decorated as follows:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

**Update**

So after some discussion in chat, it seems the annotations within MVC 4 behave a little differently than with MVC 3.  Specifically, with the above annotations for MVC 3, the following HTML would be rendered:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"
    type="text" value="11/15/2013" />
```

However, with MVC 4, there's a slight difference:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="StartDate" name="StartDate"
    type="date" value="11/15/2013" />
```

Notice that it changes the input type to `date`.  This was causing a datepicker to automatically be shown in Chrome, which was undesired behaviour.

The problem here is that the date formatting will be applied via `Html.EditorFor`, but not with `Html.TextBoxFor`.  `Html.TextBoxFor` can be passed CSS classes to change the behaviour, but `Html.EditorFor` doesn't have that kind of overload.

For possible solutions to this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454374/729541).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, however, when I'm binding to that it doesn't like trying to convert `StartDate = n.StartDate,`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'string'

Comment: linq to entities does not recognize .ToString()

Comment: @JonHarding Oh, that's my mistake, sorry.  The property type should be `DateTime` (possibly `DateTime?` if that matches your database schema).

Comment: That, unfortunately, is still giving me the date with as '11/11/2013 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: @JonHarding The data annotations require the use of the `Html.DisplayFor` / `Html.EditorFor` helpers to work.  The helpers apply the characteristics of the attributes.

Comment: @JonHarding There's one other detail too.  I'll update my answer to make things clearer.

Comment: I was using `TextBoxFor` do the annotations not work for that?

Comment: @JonHarding They do, but see my edit: `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` is what you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41231/discussion-between-jon-harding-and-john-h)

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to use Today as the start date when the date value is null. Logically, that would mean something will start from today instead of an empty string, which is both confusing and difficult to understand.

Comment: StartDate is pulled from the database, it isnt a representation of todays date