# ASP.NET MVC5 Ajax form post model with null?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

whatever I submit the form ,the Comment object just have one value [Comment Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyVlz.png)
but the pages look like this
[Create Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ8Xf.png)
Why aren't the ViewModel values posting correctly?

```
public class CommentViewModel{

    public Comment comment { get; set; }
    public UploadFile Uploadfile { get; set; }
}
```

This is Comment class:

```
public class Comment{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string review { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This is View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxopts)){

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Comment</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.FileId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FileId must be a number." data-val-required="FileId is necessary" id="FileId" name="FileId" type="number" value="@ViewBag.FileId"  />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

   <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreateDate must be a date." data-val-required="CreateDate is necessary" id="CreateDate" name="CreateDate" type="datetime" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" />

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

  <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="UserId" name="UserId" type="text" value="@User.Identity.Name.ToString()"  />

   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comment.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comment.review, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comment.review, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /> 
}
```

This is Controller:

```
  public ActionResult CreateCommets(Comment comment){

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        List<Comment> Commentlist = (from p in db.Comments where p.FileId == comment.FileId select p).ToList();
        return PartialView("_CommentsView",Commentlist);
    }
```

Comment: is there a [HttpPost] attribute on the CreateComments Function?

Comment: yeah,I add it before I create the question

Comment: can you explain 'ajaxopts' ?

Comment: AjaxOptions ajaxopts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "post",
        UpdateTargetId = "comments",
        Url = Url.Action("CreateCommets", "UploadFiles"),
        LoadingElementId = "loading",
        LoadingElementDuration = 2000
    };

Comment: use CommentViewModel in your action method parameter. public ActionResult CreateCommets(CommentViewModel commentViewModel){//code}

Comment: but I post Comment

Comment: why not just use `html.beginform` ? any particular reason for using ajax?

Comment: I want to use ajax to update commets but the Web page don't change

Comment: try using `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`

Comment: I used Editfor before ,but useless

Comment: Because the model in your view is `CommentViewModel` which means the parameter in your method needs to be `public ActionResult CreateCommets(CommentViewModel model) {` (not `Comment comment`). Or you could use `public ActionResult CreateCommets([Bind(Prefix = "comment")]Comment model)`

Comment: But your not understanding what a view model is. It should not contain properties which are data model. It should contain one property for each property of `Comment` that you want to display/edit in the view plus the `Uploadfile` file property.

Comment: I don't think so, because I find the reason is I shouldn't use '<input> ‘ instead of 'Html.Editor()'

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried HTML helper class for Input type eg:

```
 @Html.Textboxfor(m=>m.comment.CreateDate, new  { @class="",@type="datetime",@value="@DateTime.Now.ToString()"})
```

Comment: Please try this: 

<input type="text" name="comment.CreateDate" value="@DateTime.Now"/>

Answer (score 0):

For Userid, CreateDate and FileID try and use an Editor for. You can apply your custom class [by looking at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor)

Comment: but they shouldn't be changed

Answer (score -2):

Please update your view code....

```
 @model ApplicationName.Models.Comment

 <h4>Comment</h4>
 <hr />
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

 <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FileId must be a number." data-val-required="FileId is necessary" id="FileId" name="FileId" type="number" value="@ViewBag.FileId" />

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

 <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreateDate must be a date." data-val-required="CreateDate is necessary" id="CreateDate" name="CreateDate" type="datetime" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" />

  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

  <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="UserId" name="UserId" type="text" value="@User.Identity.Name.ToString()" />

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.review, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.review, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Comment: You can directly access your model like this way..

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)

Or if you are working with the mvc pattren then you have to use 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.CreateDate, new {@class="", @type="datetime", @value="@DateTimeNow.ToString"})

Comment: If you have any problem with this please let me know, i will provide you better explaination.

Comment: I use @model MVCdemo.Models.CommentViewModel becasue they are two models

Comment: if you are using two model..why not you are using partial view?

Comment: yeah,I use some partial view

Comment: I can't understand you, please provide your full code, how you are using

Comment: I share it to google https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6XkUOlmSKWUSERfb0ZFVFFHc0k

Comment: Hi...@CBBing please use the another partial view under the @Html.Partial("_CommentsView") 
@Html.Partial("_CommentsFormView")
Inside this _CommentsFormView you have to use single model Comment and use my above answer view html

Comment: let me explain what I do.I want to create Comment just like I create Comment now,I don't want this web page Reload and show the Comment

Comment: I use Ajax.BeginForm to post Comment ,but I received  "NULL"