# Change class of @Html.EditorFor / customize template | ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I want to change the class/style of my @Html.EditorFor field. I read something about customizing the template, but there is no template folder in my porject (Views/Shared/ONLY_FILES_HERE). Sadly I am **NOT** working with MVC 5.1.

Also I **DON'T** want to use TextBoxFor, because of inputvalidation.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a snippet of my model:

```
public class CreateTableColumnModels
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters and numbers only please")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I tried this:

```
@model QlikViewStammdaten.Models.CreateTableColumnModels
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Have tried with : @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.MyProperty,
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "MyCssClass" } })

Comment: Just create the Editor/DisplayTemplates folders inside Views/Shared folder and add a <classname>.cshtml

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes, it's for >=MVC 5.1

Comment: Take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577748/7124761

Comment: @phuzi so the file would be CreateTableColumnModels.cshtml

Comment: @PrashantPimpale sorry, i forgot to mention that i don't want to use TextBoxFor

Comment: @DavidWalser yep. Make sure the the model used by the template is also CreateTableColumnModels

Comment: @phuzi it's not working with the code above :/ the file is named CreateTableColumnModels.cshtml

Comment: @phuzi don't let me down :(

Comment: What is wrong with using `TextBoxFor`? (they ultimately call the same code anyway). And there is no issue with validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke for example when a field is for integers users are allowed to write chars into TextBoxFor, but NOT in EditorFor

Comment: Then just add `type = "number"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke hmm ok thanks, I'm fine with that solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, it is better to add a class to `Html.TextBoxFor` and NOT `@Html.EditorFor`. Why? because `@Html.EditorFor` renders a template and that template could contain multiple controls (now to which one of those controls do you want to add the class?)... see [Adding a class to EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor/4577748#4577748)

If you want numeric type, then add `@type = "number"`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number"  })
```

*Note: it is not `x => Model.Name` but `m => m.Name`*

*I am sure you already know this, but `[Display(Name = "Name")]` is redundant in your model, as the default display name is the variable name itself.*