# Add a class to TextBoxFor

Tags: html, css, entity-framework, bootstrap-4

How can I add the form-control class to this TextBoxFor? I'm new to coding.

```html
<div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <Label class="center-block">Hours</Label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:-1%" class="form-group text-center">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.hours, new { type = "number", min = "0", step = "1", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control center-block" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor - Adding class to EditorFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where `htmlAttributes` is coming from here, but you're already within the context of setting HTML attributes in that object, such as `type` and `min` and `step`.  You're also setting `@class` in your `ValidationMessageFor`, why not apply that same standard?

Just remove the `htmlAttributes` and set the `@class` property on the object that has the other attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
  model => model.hours,
  new {
    type = "number",
    min = "0",
    step = "1",
    @class = "form-control center-block"
  })
```